# Setting AVAudioPlayer Delegate to multiple classes?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, avaudioplayer

Quick question: Is it possible to set the delegate of an AVAudioPlayer instance to more than one class?

In my program, I want two classes to be notified when a sound has been finished playing, but I am unsure of how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is something not possible. but you can do it by registering and notifying notification. [Here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html) is code for registering and notifying classes in objective c.

So you can set one class a delegate and there you can notify other classes

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"delegate called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                postNotificationName:AUDIO_PLAYER_FINISHED_PLAYING object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a delegate is always just one instance.
You could make a new class that is the delegate and make it send an NSNotification to notify the other two classes about the event.